# How to remove '/' from end of Sinatra routes

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra and the shotgun server.

When I type in `http://localhost:9393/tickets`, my page loads as expected. But, with an extra "`/`" on the end, Sinatra suggests that I add

```
get '/tickets/' do
```

How do I get the server to accept the extra "`/`" without creating the extra route?

The information in Sinatra's "[How do I make the trailing slash optional?](http://sinatrarb.com/faq.html#slash)" section looks useful, but this means I would need to add this code to every single route.

Is there an easier or more standard way to do that?

My route is set up as

```
get '/tickets' do
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We need to see how you're defining your routes. Right now you're asking us to imagine your code and that doesn't work well. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages and See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".
.

Comment: It's probably smarter, more self-documenting, and easier in the long run, to put the `/?` on routes that need it, rather than try to figure out logic to selectively NOT do that on routes where you don't want it to happen. "[Custom Route Matchers](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html)" might help you, but again, moving the logic elsewhere could paint you into a corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the FAQ doesn't mention an option that was added in 2017 (https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/1273/commits/2445a4994468aabe627f106341af79bfff24451e)

Put this in the same scope where you are defining your routes:

```
set :strict_paths, false
```

With this, Sinatra will treat `/tickets/` as if it were `/tickets` so you don't need to add `/?` to all your paths

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually bigger than it appears at first glance. Following the advice in "[How do I make the trailing slash optional?](http://sinatrarb.com/faq.html#slash)" does solve the problem, but:

- it requires you to modify all existing routes, and
- it creates a "duplicate content" problem, where identical content is served from multiple URLs.

Both of these issues are solvable but I believe a cleaner solution is to create a redirect for all non-root URLs that end with a `/`. This can easily be done by adding [Sinatra's `before` filter](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) into the existing application controller:

```
before '/*/' do
  redirect request.path_info.chomp('/')
end

get '/tickets' do
  …
end
```

After that, your existing `/tickets` route will work as it did before, but now all requests to `/tickets/` will be redirected to `/tickets` before being processed as normal.

Thus, the application will respond on both `/ticket` and `/tickets/` endpoints without you having to change any of the existing routes.

**PS:** Redirecting the root URL (eg: `http://localhost:9393/` → `http://localhost:9393`) will create an infinite loop, so you definitely don't want to do that.